# Как сделать так, чтобы при наборе текста в данном случае выдавалось "Incorrect valuе"?

Tags: python

```
a = input('Enter the right answer: ')
b = int(a)
b != str(a)
if b == 440:
    print('Correct answer')
elif b == str(a):
    print("Incorrect value")
else:
    print('Incorrect answer')
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при наборе, например, букв выдавался ответ incorrect value? Как будто онлайн тест, в котором есть только один вариант ответа в числовом виде. Если вводишь текст - то пусть отвечает "неверное значение", а при неверном числовом - "неверный ответ".

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы при наборе, например, букв выдавался ответ incorrect value? 
Как будто онлайн тест, в котором есть только 1 вариант ответа в числовом виде. Если вводишь текст - то пусть отвечает "неверное значение", а при неверном числовом - "неверный ответ".

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите полное опписание требуемого поведения в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно такую проверку на треш вместо числа использовать:

```
a = input('Enter the right answer: ')

try:
    answer = int(a)
    if answer == 440:
        print("corrent answer")
    else:
        print("incorrect answer")
except:
    print("incorrent value")
```

если происходит ошибка при преобразовании строки в число, то происходит ошибка (срабатывает исключение) и выводится соответствующий текст

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, с проверкой и отрицательных чисел тоже :)

```
a = input('Enter the right answer: ')
if ans.isdigit() or ans.replace('-', '', 1).isdigit():
    if int(ans)=='440': print('Correct answer')
    else: print('Incorrect answer')
else: print("Incorrect value")
```

В данном случае метод `.isdigit()` проверяет, введены ли в строке *только* числа или нет (возвращает `True` / `False`).

Answer (score -2):

```py
if input('Enter the right answer: ').isnumeric():
    print('Correct value')
else:
    print('Incorrect value')
```

str.isnumeric() - Возвращает флаг что строка содержит ли только числа.

Comment: попробуйте: `print("-15".isnumeric())`, если же говорить про числа с плавающей запятой, то там вообще все печально будет с такой проверкой